# Is 'you' an exclamative in 'you fools'

Tags: exclamatives

In the Lord of the Rings, Gandalf yells this famous line:

> Fly, **you** fools!

Now, I am wondering what the function of 'you' is. Is it an exclamation? The Collins Dictionary uses the examples 'what' and 'how' in a similar way ([link here](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/what-are-exclamations-and-interjections-in-english)). I believe 'such' could also fall under this categorisation.

Answer (score 11):

"You" in this position functions as a determiner.  (examples adapted from Wiktionary)

> Have you gentlemen come to see the house?

> You idiot!

Determiners function to identify the thing referred to by a noun.  So the determiner "these" identifies it as "the ones close to me"  "These fools are....". But the determiner "you" identifies the noun as being the person addressed by the speaker.

So "You fools" means "the fools, who are you."  But it is an emphatic form, used most often with an epithet (like "fool")

Comment: Probably its most common usage is in phrases such as “you guys”.

Comment: Is this a demonstrative determiner? That is the only category I think it fits in.

Comment: It's a determiner. I don't feel the need to subcategorise in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the more important question is: what is the role of "*fools*" in the sentence?" Whatever "you" is doing here, it's doing it together with "fools" as a phrase. The phrase "you fools" is directly mentioned in [this book about syntax](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Syntax_of_Nonsententials/I22xD1Abb28C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=you%20fools%20appositive). Although the discussion is way above my pay grade, one phrase jumps out: "you fools" is "a kind of integrated appositive." ([Appositives](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html), oversimplified, add one noun to another to help clarify.) It's also clear that, since Gandalf is addressing the party directly, the phrase is a [vocative](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/easy-learning/what-is-the-vocative-in-english). A [vocative](https://www.thoughtco.com/vocative-grammar-1692598) is simply a direct address (so, in the sentences "Run, Forrest!" or "Bring out the ring, Frodo," *Forrest* and *Frodo* are vocatives, as well as the subjects of their imperative sentences.

In an earlier edit of this answer, I suggested that the vocative "you fools" was functioning as a subject in the sentence. However, [vocatives cannot be subjects](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/direct-address.html). So the answer to the original question is simply: "you" is an appositive in the vocative phrase "you fools."

Comment: Although the implied subject of an imperative is “you”, when it’s expressed, it must precede the verb, not follow it.You can get both in the same sentence: *You stop it, you!*

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. So wait, what *is* the subject? A second, implied "you"?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.